# Sql Anywhere 17 ef code first migrations support

Tags: .net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I tried to use the SQL Anywhere ADO.NET Provider for EF6, using code first approach with migrations.

When I try to add a migration I receive this error:

"No MigrationSqlGenerator found for provider 'Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere'. Use the SetSqlGenerator method in the target migrations configuration class to register additional SQL generators.".

I just saw this link "http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/questions/12780/entity-framework-code-first-migrations" but is older and there isn't a significant answer.

Someone can help Me to understand if it will be a next feature or instead there is no support?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support available for migrations with that provider